# Displaying two foreign keys linked with one primary key

Tags: sql, oracle

These are my tables

```
Stop

id     name
a        place1
b        place2          
c        place3
d        place4
e        place5
f        place6
g        place7

Trip

id       start       finish
1          a            c
3          d            f
4          e            g
5          b            f
```

At the moment I'm using following sql query:

```
SELECT trip.id, starts, ends
FROM trip,
(SELECT name as starts
FROM trip, stop
WHERE stop.id=trip.start),
(SELECT name as ends
FROM trip, stop
WHERE stop.id=trip.finish);
```

Which gives me this look

```
id       starts       ends
1        place1       place7
2        place1       place7
3        place1       place7
4        place1       place7
5        place1       place7
1        place1       place6
and so on...
```

I want display the contect of Trip table with stop ids (a,b,c..) replaced with their assigned names.

```
id       start       finish
1        place1      place3
3        place4      place6
4        place5      place7
5        place2      place6
```

Stop id and Trip id are PKs,
Start and Finish columns from Trip table are foreign keys of Stop id from Stop table. I work on oracle developer ver 3.2.
Can you please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you lookng for this?

```
SELECT
    T.id,
    S1.name Start,
    S2.name End
FROM Trip T
    JOIN Stop S1
        T.Start = S1.Id
    JOIN Stop S2
        T.End = S2.Id
```